# Ruby convert expanded if statement into one-liner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, syntactic-sugar

Is there a nicer way to write this if/else statement, given that there’s only a tiny difference between the two parts?

```
if current_admin_user.role?(:admin)
  f.input :invoice_file_date, as: :datepicker if f.object.invoice_file.present?
else
  f.input :invoice_file_date, as: :datepicker, :input_html => { :disabled => true } if f.object.invoice_file.present?
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recall if `:disabled => false` will do what you want or if that's one of those "only check if the attribute exists not the value" ones, but this would work.  Not sure it's better though.

```
f.input :invoice_file_date, as: :datepicker, 
        :input_html => { :disabled => !current_admin_user.role?(:admin) } if f.object.invoice_file.present?
```

Comment: This is a really neat solution. Thank you!